# SQL exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'chatid' at row 1 for SELECT query

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to run a select query as below

```
Statement st2=con.createStatement(); 

String Query2= "SELECT chatid from messagingapp where senderid ='uzO8Epn9j5YcTyD1Z2JZBgplFrB2'  AND receiverid='1jFWGck9JuUXnSHgzNCQAd2TtIj1'";

ResultSet rs2= st2.executeQuery(Query2);
```

I am getting exception error as
`java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'chatid' at row 1`

MY database properties is

```
name :chatid type :INT  AutoIncrement:yes pk:yes
name:senderid type :varchar 
name:receiverid type :varchar
```

Comment: can you please post more code and table structure?

Comment: Also post the complete stack trace. This makes it easier to narrow down the problem